# How to use manage_$post_type_posts_columns with underscore in post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, filters

I have a post type `'job_listing'` and I want to use `manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns` filter in it. I tried `manage_job_listing_posts_columns` but it's not working because of the underscore in the post type.

The code I tried is:

```
  add_filter('manage_job_listing_posts_columns', 'add_more_column_to_post', 10, 1);

  function add_more_column_to_post ($posts_columns) {
    $posts_columns[ 'featured' ] = __( 'Select Featured Post' );
    return $posts_columns;
  }
```

Comment: I just did a quick test and it it works just fine with an underscore in the post type slug. Please post the relevant code-- you CPT registration function, your `manage_` filter code, etc.

Comment: I tried with 
 add_filter('manage_job_listing_posts_columns', 'add_more_column_to_post', 10, 1);

  function add_more_column_to_post ($posts_columns) {
    $posts_columns[ 'featured' ] = __( 'Select Featured Post' );
    return $posts_columns;
  }
But the column is not showing in the table for this post type in wp-admin

Comment: Your code works for me. There are ___details missing from this question___, as least some of which I have asked for already and which you have still not included. The problem is somewhere in those missing details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this exact same issue, but it's a problem with the Jobroller theme (seeing as the custom post type is `job_listing`, I'm guessing you're using Jobroller as well).

The Jobroller theme adds the custom columns to the `job_listing` custom post type using the function `jr_edit_jobs_columns` in the file `jobroller/includes/admin/admin-post-types.php`:

```php
function jr_edit_jobs_columns( $columns ){
    $columns = array(
        'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />',
        'title' => __('Job Name', APP_TD),
        'author' => __('Job Author', APP_TD),
        'job_cat' => __('Job Category', APP_TD),
        'job_type' => __('Job Type', APP_TD),
        'job_salary' => __('Salary', APP_TD),
        'company' => __('Company', APP_TD),
        'location' => __('Location', APP_TD),
        'expire_date' => __('Expire Date', APP_TD),
        'date' => __('Date', APP_TD),
        'logo' => __('Logo', APP_TD),
    );
    return $columns;
}
```

But this function does it incorrectly, it simply redefines the columns instead of adding and removing columns to the existing list. So any columns you add in a child theme will be removed before the page is rendered (Because child themes get executed first).

You should edit that function like so:

```php
function jr_edit_jobs_columns( $columns ){
    $new_columns = array(
        'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />',
        'title' => __('Job Name', APP_TD),
        'author' => __('Job Author', APP_TD),
        'job_cat' => __('Job Category', APP_TD),
        'job_type' => __('Job Type', APP_TD),
        'job_salary' => __('Salary', APP_TD),
        'company' => __('Company', APP_TD),
        'location' => __('Location', APP_TD),
        'expire_date' => __('Expire Date', APP_TD),
        'date' => __('Date', APP_TD),
        'logo' => __('Logo', APP_TD),
    );
    unset($columns['cb']);
    unset($columns['title']);
    unset($columns['author']);
    unset($columns['taxonomy-job_location']);
    unset($columns['taxonomy-job_cat']);
    unset($columns['comments']);
    unset($columns['date']);
    return $new_columns + $columns; // This way your custom columns are at the end
}
```